# Cannot register SPN, error 0x80090350, state 4

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, authentication, active-directory, kerberos

This is my first time trying to configure kerberos. I need it for SQL Server.

**Considerations**

- I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 2008 R2 server.
- I have an Active Directory account for SQL Server 2008 R2.
- The account is delegated for kerberos.
- The account is configured to start SQL Server services. This works without problems.
- SPNs are registered for both netbios and FQDN for computername and also `computername:1433.`
- The same SPNS are registered for the server and the account.

I mean, if I do

- `setspn -L domain\serviceaccount`

or

- `setsqpn -Q MSSSQLSvc/Server.domain.local`,

I get

```
MSSQLSvc/Server:1433

MSSQLSvc/Server.domain.local

MSSQLSvc/Server.domain.local:1433
```

When I run this query:

```
select auth_scheme 
  from sys.dm_exec_connections 
 where session_id=@@spid
```

...the result is **NTLM**.

This query I'm running from another server, connecting to the SQL Server that I need to use Kerberos on.

When I restart SQL Server services I see this error in the log:

> The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. `Error: 0x80090350, state: 4.` Failure to register an SPN may cause integrated authentication to fall back to NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you're seeing, 0x80090350, is defined as:

```
c:\util\Err>err 0x80090350

# for hex 0x80090350 / decimal -2146892976 :
  SEC_E_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED                                        winerror.h
# The system detected a possible attempt to compromise
# security.  Please ensure that you can contact the server
# that authenticated you.
# 1 matches found for "0x80090350"
```

I'm looking this up with the [Exchange Error Lookup Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985).

According to the information in [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds//?PageIndex=1&pi136234=2&PostSortBy=MostComments&pi168922=22#kerb) post, this error is often caused by the [MaxTokenSize](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/327825) issue caused by an account (indirectly or directly) being a member of a [large number of groups](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/327825).

Another possibility I'd consider is that a duplicate SPN exists. You can determine which SPNs Windows thinks are duplicates by running `setspn -X -F` (info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/02/13/searching-for-duplicate-spn-s-got-a-little-easier.aspx])).

Comment: The SQL service account is member of 6 groups. I searched for duplicate SPNs and there are 2 for another server, an old server that is no longer in use. Nothing showed up for the SQL service account or the SQL server. What if I change the service account to local system and let the server take care of it?

Comment: I think local system doesn't have network access, which might cause some issues for you. How many groups are those 6 groups members of? Any chance the server is having trouble contacting a domain controller, or there's another machine on the network with the same name as the DC or the SQL Server? Any more details at all in the application, security, or system logs on the server?

Comment: Ok...no local system. The account is member of Administrators, Domain Admins, Enterprise Admins, Domain Users, Group Policy Creators Owners, Schema Admins. The machine is a server, there is no other machine with the same name, I have not seen any logs showing errors between the machine and the DCs. The only thing I've seen is the error stated that the SPN cannot be created. Other than that I have not seen other errors.

Comment: In that case your best bet might be to work through one of the guides to troubleshooting Kerberos errors like [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=21820).

Comment: As an aside, I'd be really uncomfortable running SQL Server as a forest, schema, or domain admin, but that's unrelated to your concern with Kerberos AFAIK. Probably best to continue in chat if there are any further comments at this point...

Comment: Thank you for the document. I'll look at it and message you for updates. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at all the steps again I noticed that the account didn't have permissions to read and write SPNs. Modiefied the values with ADSI edit.

Thanks for all the help!